# How can apply role based authentication in a mean app?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am working on a mean stack application and want to apply role based authentication .
for example if the is off admin he/she can access or have some more rights
any help will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Some things you'll find useful when building role based Authentication:

- Angular routing based on modules and children
- Route guards
- Depending on your resources, saving sessions with role information via exchange of JSON Web Tokens or Cookies

Ryan Chenkie has some good tutorials on securing Angular Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://catalin.me/role-based-authentication-with-angular-express-jwt-mysql-part-1/) article was old but can be helpful.

You just need to change the stack what he used.